# Migration of Geonetwork 4.0.0 from one ubuntu machine to other

Tags: java-8, migration, tomcat9, geonetwork

I am facing challenge in migrting geonetwork from one machine to another.

Geonetwork 4.0.0 is running on an UBUNTU 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64). It was installed using .WAR file and run in Apache Tomcat 9/JAVA 8 environment.

Current/Running geonetwork application is ingested with following records:

- The geonetwork user interface is customised using geonetwork's own settings/dashboard.
- **Metadata along with thumbnails **are inserted and published for almost 100 layers. All the entries were WMS records.

While the migration process seemed to go smoothly, I've encountered issues where metadata, thumbnails, and styles are not reflecting on the new machine with an identical environment.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue during GeoNetwork migration? Are there specific steps I might be missing or configurations that need extra attention? Additionally, could there be any dependencies on the server-specific details that I might have overlooked?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Steps followed were:

1. copied geonetwork folder from webapps.
2. did not copied elastic search database as the data folder of geonetwork might contain the metadata in XML formats.
3. the copied folder is moved to the new machine.
4. The folder is copied into tomcat's webapps folder and changed the ownership to tomcat.
5. The tomcat service is restarted and the it shows message that tomcat started successfully with Java 8.
6. The geonetwork's default interface is opened at 8080 port without any metadata.

Despite following these steps, the metadata, thumbnails, and styles are not reflecting correctly on the new server.